# Why isn't "--comment" working when "-- comment" does?

Tags: php, mysql

I've finally found why my PHP script didn't work. It was because of MySQL "--comment" instead of "-- comment". I recently started with PHP, and until then, I had always used "--comment". Now, I wonder why this isn't allowed in PHP's mysql_query()?

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT firstname,
-- comment
lastname, address,
--not a comment
age FROM friends WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'";

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

?>
```

Comment: why are you putting comments in the query? just use php comment blocks

Comment: @Neal Queries are loaded with file_get_contents().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html) a space is required. Also, as stated on the previous linked page, MySQL deviates from the spec in this syntax (which is just 2 consecutive dashes [`--this is a comment`]).

Comment: Thank you! Now I really understand why "--not a comment" isn't allowed in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL comments beginning with `--` *must* be followed by a space in order to be considered a comment. This is something specific to MySQL, and has nothing to do with PHP. You may also use `/* comment */` or `# comment #`

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comments.html):
*the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on).*

Answer (score 1):

Because the MySQL dev team decided that **if** `SELECT -1` is valid code to select -1
then `SELECT --1` Should be valid (My)SQL for selecting +1.

Answer (score 0):

Because a comment starts with three characters: dash, dash, space. "-- "